# PHP implode multidimensional array - unable to access an array within an array

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array, implode

Attempting to implode a multidimensional array as follows:

```
"data": [
        {
            "1": "",
            "2": "211",
            "3": 0,
            "x": [
                2661.898,
                0
            ],
            "4": 2662.138,
            "5": 0,
            "y": [
                166,
                0
            ]}
    ]
```

PHP Code

```
$json =  file_get_contents( 'myjson' );
$implode = array();
$multiple = json_decode( $json, true );
    foreach ( $multiple[ "data" ] as $key => $single)

        $implode[] = is_array($single) ? implode( ', ', $single) : $single ;

echo implode( '<br>', $implode );
```

At present I get results like this as I am failing to access the nested arrays.

```
0, 211, 0, Array, 2662.138, 0, Array
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I access those nested arrays? I would like the code to just go into any nested array and not have to call them by name so x[0], y[1] etc.

Comment: Aren't you seeing a _Notice: Array to string conversion_ on the `implode` line?

Comment: not sure what you mean. I have never seen a message like that.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: this is the error: Notice: Array to string conversion in /test.php on line 163

Comment: this is the bit that causes the error: $implode[] = is_array($single) ? implode( ', ', $single) : $single ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do the trick.

```
$s = '
{"data": [
        {
            "1": "",
            "2": "211",
            "3": 0,
            "x": [
                2661.898,
                0
            ],
            "4": 2662.138,
            "5": 0,
            "y": [
                166,
                0
            ]}
    ]}';

$aData   = json_decode($s, true);
$implode = array();

foreach ($aData["data"] as $pos => &$v) {

    foreach ($v as $pos2 => $v2) {
        if(is_array($v2)){
            $aData["data"][$pos][$pos2] = implode(',', $v2);
        }
    }

    $implode[] = implode(',', $v);
}

var_dump($implode);
```

Produces

```
array(7) {
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
  [2]=>
  string(3) "211"
  [3]=>
  int(0)
  ["x"]=>
  string(10) "2661.898,0"
  [4]=>
  float(2662.138)
  [5]=>
  int(0)
  ["y"]=>
  string(5) "166,0"
}
```

Comment: this culls the loop but I wanted to avoid having to list out the nested arrays as there are quite a few. I simply want to decode everything to one long string

Comment: I've given that a go but it is still showing me Array instead of the 2 values that are within that nested array

Comment: I was missing the reference symbol `&`. Please see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

you can use recursion:

```
<?php
$json = "{\n\"data\": [\n        {\n            \"1\": \"\",\n            \"2\": \"211\",\n            \"3\": 0,\n            \"x\": [\n                2661.898,\n                0\n            ],\n            \"4\": 2662.138,\n            \"5\": 0,\n            \"y\": [\n                166,\n                0\n            ]}\n    ]\n}";


$multiple = json_decode( $json, true );



function recursive_implode(array $array, $glue = ',', $include_keys = false, $trim_all = true)
{
    $glued_string = '';

    // Recursively iterates array and adds key/value to glued string
    array_walk_recursive($array, function($value, $key) use ($glue, $include_keys, &$glued_string)
    {
        $include_keys and $glued_string .= $key.$glue;
        $glued_string .= $value.$glue;
    });

    // Removes last $glue from string
    strlen($glue) > 0 and $glued_string = substr($glued_string, 0, -strlen($glue));

    // Trim ALL whitespace
    $trim_all and $glued_string = preg_replace("/(\s)/ixsm", '', $glued_string);

    return (string) $glued_string;
}
echo recursive_implode($multiple['data']);
```

output:

```
,211,0,2661.898,0,2662.138,0,166,0
```

Comment: this one works too but trying to figure out where I can add a line break (<br> for simpler onscreen viewing?

Comment: just change the` $glue = ',',` parameter

Comment: I tried that and ended up with each string on a seperate line. Just looking to have each row of strings on its own row